# In mongodb , collection is there a way to encrypt few key columns and decrypt the remaining columns?

Tags: mongodb-query

I am new to mongodb and require help:

I have a collection emp and there are around 10 key columns (name,surname,emp id,sex, dept,address,telephone number, salary etc),
So want to know if there is a way to encrypt few key columns (address,telephone number and salary) and let the remaining key columns be decrypt.

Regards

Comment: does this help?  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-encryption/

Comment: Hello Nathan, Thanks for your help, my request is to encrypt few key columns in the collection but no where i didnt see that in the link provided by you. Can you help on the same?